# Image Upload to php server android

Tags: php, android, web-services

I'm Trying to upload image to serverside directory.this is my code.when i click on the submit button, it's not upload image.no any error in LogCat.

```
mBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String selectedPath = "file://storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Usage Tracker/IMG_20150916_161450.jpg";
        try{

            File file=new File(selectedPath);

            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("uploadedfile",file);
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.post("http://example.com/utracker/webservices/upload_picture.php",  params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                    String s=new String(responseBody);
                    if(s.contentEquals("Success")){                
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                       "You Have Successfully Uploaded Your Image To Our Server", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {             
        }
    }
}
```

PHP script

```
<?php
    $target_path = "../uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
        echo "Success";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: change it to `catch (Exception e)
                 {
e.printStackTrace();
                 }` to get the exception.it is ignoring all exceptions.

Comment: @sourabhbans LogCat show `09-16 16:54:33.747: D/dalvikvm(20270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 993K, 31% free 18441K/26592K, paused 13ms, total 16ms`

Comment: have you set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> permission in your Android Manifest file?

Comment: I tried uploading an image to your server and I got the success response :P Try to print the string String s=new String(responseBody) and see what's the response.

Comment: @PETER ohh man =D.can you share with me your code please.

Comment: @ChaturaDilan yes i've set permission

Comment: @Yash, I tried it from Advanced rest client extension for google chrome, not from android. So it's clear that php code is accepting the image. But it's always better to keep the response from php as JSON instead of usual string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the success or failure for image upload by printing inside echo 
You have to return a json encoded response to android and then check whether it is success or failure

```
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Success";
            echo json_encode($response);
         }
        else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Failure";
            echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

Refer this Link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql